# SQL query on H2 database table throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: sql, h2, indexoutofboundsexception, dbvisualizer, large-data

I have a H2 database on which some queries work, while others are throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

For example:

```
SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM MY_TABLE; // works fine


SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_1) FROM MY_TABLE; // gives following error message:
[Error Code: 50000, SQL State: HY000]  
General error: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"; 
SQL statement: SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_1) FROM MY_TABLE [50000-167]
```

What is the cause for this eror message?

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace please? Please note according to the error code, this is H2 version 1.3.167, which is relatively old.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the old H2 version. I wasn't aware it became so outdated. Trying to get the stacktrace again led me on the right track (see answer below), so thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the error message was a **corrupt database.**

**I resolved the problem by using the H2 Recovery Tool.** The steps were the following:

1. Create the recovery script

   ```
   C:\PATH_TO_CORRUPT_DB>java -cp C:\PATH_TO_MY_H2\h2.jar org.h2.tools.Recover
   ```
2. Delete the old db file (not without making a backup copy first, of course ;-))
3. Recreate the database

   ```
   C:\PATH_TO_CORRUPT_DB>java -cp C:\PATH_TO_MY_H2\h2.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:PATH_TO_CORRUPT_DB\NAME_OF_DB -script NAME_OF_SCRIPT_FROM_STEP_ONE.sql
   ```

Here you can find a [more detailed usage description of the H2 Recovery Tool](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#using_recover_tool)