# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-178]

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2, h2db

> I have a small 30 MB h2 database file. Driver version is 1.4.178.
>   Everything worked fine but recently the DB stop to work with
>   exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-178] 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:294) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:293) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:256) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:57) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:164) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:142) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:125) 
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:150) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.parseMap(DataUtils.java:630) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.openMap(MVStore.java:411) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.<init>(TransactionStore.java:96) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.<init>(MVTableEngine.java:161) 
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:94) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2355) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:659) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:262) 
    ... 7 more 

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:610) 
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:129) 
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:434) 
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:315) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91) 
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:74) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:684) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.test(WebApp.java:896) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:222) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:171) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:138) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:94) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The problem occurs in my application and using H2 web frontend.

Comment: check this link if it is related to your problem (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/iAQ7ImUvEhA)

Comment: no,that is related to primary key. we are facing the problem to connect to H2 db starting it self

Comment: Did you try with the latest version of H2 (1.4.188?)

Comment: I followed this link using latest version H2(1.4.188) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428741/sql-query-on-h2-database-table-throws-arrayindexoutofboundsexception but new database created with out copying old data

Comment: same error using latest version H2 (1.4.188)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you're trying to fix the cause of this NPE or if you're trying to retrieve the content of the database.

I suggest the following:

- retrieve your data using procedure described at http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore
- upgrade your stack to move to the last version of 1.3 (176) or the latest 1.4 (188).
- restore the data with this new stack
- run and test your server

If the NPE problem still occurs, you'll need to provide more details in this forum.

Comment: I have been trying to restore the data. backup of data base script created but when restore it throws below error C:\GamificationDB>java -cp C:\GamificationDB\h2-1.4.188.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/GamificationDB  -script test.zip -options compression zip
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function alias "READ_BLOB" already exists; SQL statement:

CREATE FORCE ALIAS PUBLIC.READ_BLOB FOR "org.h2.tools.Recover.readBlob" [90076-188]

Comment: Please let me know what details you need to fix NPN

Comment: @SubhaChandra more context of the application is needed. example: what software stack is used, what type of SQL tables are you using, jdbc URLs, etc... The fact you cannot recreate a clean db from a restore is interesting. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Did you try editing the sql inside test.zip and comment the offending line "CREATE FORCE ALIAS PUBLIC.READ_BLOB..." ?